# Is there a difference between recovering data from the original drive VS a clone of it

Tags: macos, data-recovery

Following up from [How to create an accurate byte-level copy of an SSD to another drive?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/364681/how-to-create-an-accurate-byte-level-copy-of-an-ssd-to-another-drive), I did a clone of my entire internal 256GB SSD of my Mac 10.14, with 13-15GB free areas. I have .img file now.

Will trying to do data recovery from a clone of a drive affect the chances of recovery VS doing recovery on the drive itself? Do all data recovery software that can attempt to recover data on the original drive also be able to attempt to recover data from .img clone that I have?

Comment: What steps made the clone? (Precise commands if you have them) your statement generalizing to all data recovery software also limits your options to the lowest common denominator. My hunch is your clone could lose a lot of data and possibly  limit recovery, Also, the mac model and drive controller chip will affect your chances dramatically.

Comment: @jksoegaard after the .img file / clone is made. How will a data recovery recognise it as something I would like to do a recovery on? Most software will only show partitions and drives and require a user to choose one to do recovery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there's no difference when you have a byte-for-byte identical clone as you have. And yes, data recovery software should work the same for an original drive as for an image-based clone.

In other cases than yours there could be a slight difference - namely when we're dealing with defective hardware. If you have a broken hard drive for example it might be that if you do a naive clone multiple times, you'll end up with different images. That is not good.

In your case, I advised you to use "dd" to create a clone. That works perfectly well with functioning hardware.

If you had broken hardware, I would have advised instead to use "ddrescue". That utility has support for things like reading the same block multiple times in order to get as much correct data as possible from a malfunctioning drive. Also it can do stuff like leave holes in the clone image that corresponds to the non-working parts of the original drive.

Note that because of TRIM a functioning SSD drive could limit your possibilities of recovering data from the clone. However if you use data recovery software you run yourself on your Mac, then the clone and the original will let you recover exactly the same data.

The only difference is if you access the flash ICs on the SSD drive directly to try to recover data that has been TRIM’ed away. However that is not possible from macOS (or Windows or similar), rather you would typically need specialized hardware and software not commonly available. If you are considering sending in your data to a professional recovery service that has these capabilities, you’ll definitely want to stop using the original drive and send that in - and the continue working on your clone drive instead. NOTE: I know of no such recovery service in existence anywhere for your hardware - I think your only bet is Apple at the moment.

Comment: I like your reasoning for HDD, but SSD don’t do block copies since the controller is faking logical storage to obscure things like COW, TRIM, etc....  my gut feeling is the answer should be, yes there are massive differences and the clone is mostly useless for recovery.

Comment: @bmike That’s a misunderstanding - what you write is completely incorrect. You can use the exact same method to create a clone of an SSD, and it will be just as good for recovery as one made of a hard drive. TRIM does not enter the picture here. CoW is not implemented by the SSD, so it doesn’t matter at all here.

Comment: @bmike With further consideration - you actually have a point! I looked back and saw that the original reason behind the clone was because the user had inadvertently deleted files from the drive. In that case TRIM does play a role, as the data could then more likely have been overwritten - or have been made inaccessible from the operating system. In any case it doesn’t change that the tools suggested are the right ones, and you cannot make a more “correct” clone from macOS. As for data recovery it is possible that more data could be recovered by accessing the SSD flash ICs directly.

Comment: However that is not really possible from macOS - so in that case an “ordinary” user would need to send in the drive to a (costly) recovery service. If that is what he wants to do - he needs to send in the original drive (without using it anymore), and not a clone.

Comment: Again. No way I would down vote your very thoughtful answer. Just that whatever copy the OP did won’t reveal any data he could have copied by finder. The “image” still trusts the filesystem view and not the storage reality.

Comment: @bmike But that's not correct... the clone is of the raw data on the drive - it does not "trust the filesystem view" - and thus can reveal data that is not reflected in for example Finder. TRIM only makes it more likely that the data is inaccessible - it doesn't mean that it is always inaccessible. Contrary to common belief it is not so that TRIM occurs immediately when you delete a file. Depending on the drive, the drivers and the file system - there can be quite a difference in timing. For example the events could be hours apart (or more). In addition TRIM doesn't necessarily make the [...]

Comment: [...] disappear - some drives keep the data visible to the operating system until it needs the space for other things. In that case the time period it is available could be days or months.

Comment: @jksoegaard if i understand your answer correctly, because an SSD has the TRIM function, there might be a case where the data I wish to recover has been TRIMed away and now reside in the SSD's flash ICs. The only way to access the SSD's ICs is through specialised hardware or software. ANY available recovery software for installation on Mac will NOT access these flash ICs. For that matter, any available clone software for installation on Mac will also not access these flash ICs. [...]

Comment: [...] Hence, a recovery (using software installed on the Mac) from a resultant clone will be the same as doing so on the original SSD, BUT it is worth to note that there is still data residing in other parts of the SSD which such software cannot access. Please let me know if I am correct? Please also pardon any gaps in my knowledge.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Although it is mainly a theoretical option to get to the data residing in other parts of the SSD. I know bmike brought it up, but it is really, really, really difficult to get at because you have a Mac with the T2-chip. It’s not something a regular data recovery company can help you with. I think only Apple could potentially get to this data - but I doubt they will help you.

Comment: ok thank you for the confirmation. Btw, you said: “you’ll definitely want to stop using the original drive and send that in - and then continue working on your clone drive instead”. May I know how did you envision this to be done? [...]

Comment: [...] My machine is a Macbook Pro 15-inch (A1990 EMC3215). The shops here say they can't just take out the SSD and put in a new one for this model, is it true? (I could do that with my Macbook Air 11-inch (2013) (A1465 EMC2631) though). Any way to get around this (if getting a new machine is not an option)?

Comment: @forgodsakehold As I wrote earlier, the point raised by bmike is really mostly theoretical. I don’t know anyone who can do recovery from such a drive directly on the ICs except Apple. And they probably won’t do it for you :-) And if you need to send the drive in, you have to send the computer with it - so there’s no point in desoldering the flash ICs even if you could.

Answer (score 0):

## In your specific case

With the command you used, if dd encountered errors it just stops. So if no errors were reported when you used it, then you are good to go: there are no meaningful differences in your case as described.

The main difference is it will increase your chances of success when working with a damaged drive: Making an image/clone of a damaged drive and then working from the image (while the original is set aside someplace safe) will increase the chances of recovery because, once a drive becomes damaged, further use of the drive will often aggravate the issues. For example, using a damaged drive can corrupt more data, or do more damage and make the drive stop working altogether.

## General Answer

The command you linked `dd if=/dev/rdisk1s1 of=/Volumes/ExternalDrive/clone.img bs=1m` doesn't have the most robust options for `dd` to create an image from a *damaged* drive.

Adding `conv=noerror,sync` will make dd continue, even if errors are found, and write null bites in place of unreadable blocks.

`dd bs=4k if=/dev/rdisk1s1 of=/Volumes/ExternalDrive/clone.img conv=noerror,sync`

Alternately use a utility like `ddrescue` which has an option to specify the number of times to retry reading a block that could not be read.

Comment: You seem to have missed that this is the same guy asking follow-up questions. He hasn’t got a damaged drive, but a fully functioning drive where he accidentally deleted files he didn’t mean to delete.

Comment: Yep, I did miss that. I'll update my answer. Thank you.